# How to check if a file downloaded with Capybara/Ruby/Cucumber

Tags: ruby, download, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to verify that a downloaded file's name matches the expected name after clicking a button.

Currently, I'm navigating to Chrome's downloads page and then checking if the page contains the name of the document I want:

```
    page.driver.browser.navigate.to("chrome://downloads/")
    assert page.has_content?("document.csv")
```

However, the assertion is failing just for the Chrome downloads page. If I switch the link to another webpage and assert that the page has text/content, the assertion passes just fine.

There's something about Chrome's downloads page is not letting me validate elements on the page, which I'm guessing is because it's not an actual website. What can I do to check if the download name is on this page? Or what other way can I validate that the download actually occurred?

Comment: Can you just check the filesystem with `File.exists?`

Comment: Max, make this an answer.